# How can the concatenation of two valid LaTeX documents fail to be valid?

Tags: macros, header-footer

The question in the title is confusing, because it doesn't make sense (though it's legal) to concatenate LaTeX documents; everything after the first `\end{document}` will be ignored.  What I mean is that I had two wodges of text, `AAA` and `BBB`, such that

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{\(u\)-substitutions}
\maketitle
AAA
\end{document}
```

and

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{\(u\)-substitutions}
\maketitle
BBB
\end{document}
```

both compiled, but

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\title{\(u\)-substitutions}
\maketitle
AAA
BBB
\end{document}
```

did not.  In fact, it failed with an exceedingly strange error:

```
! LATEX ERROR: BAD MATH ENVIRONMENT DELIMITER.
```

(Those of you who sometimes misplace braces will recognise that the error is not so strange—except that LaTeX usually doesn't shout about it.)  Even more strangely, the error seemed to hop around randomly; for example, it moved to a different place if I pasted `AAA` *after* `BBB`.

Anyway, I couldn't whittle it down to a test case.  In fact, my random commenting strategy revealed at one point that including

```
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}
```

removed the error—but what does that have to do with math delimiters?

Well, I did figure out the answer, and actually laughed when I realised why the error message was in uppercase.  According to [Asking a question and answering it yourself straight away](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4/asking-a-question-and-answering-it-yourself-straight-away), it's OK to ask a question to which I know the answer, as long as I don't answer it right away; so I'll just sit tight.

Comment: Try adding `\usepackage{fixltx2e}`. Do you have `\(...\)` in section titles?

Comment: I'd never heard of that package.  Is it basically a case of "don't use it unless you need it", or is it a good idea to stick it in all my documents?  (For example, would it have helped here?  I can't tell from the summary at http://ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e.)  As to `\(...\)`—not in *section* titles, but, yes, that was the problem.

Comment: `fixltx2e` is a set of things that _really_ should be in `latex.ltx` but for various reasons are not. I always load it.

Comment: Your examples compile fine: please post what _actually_ breaks for you.

Comment: That's the problem:  I can't (or, anyway, shouldn't)!  The whole thing boiled down to whether the document compiled on a single page or not, and I don't think anyone wants me to post enough `TeX` code to fill 2 pages.  [egreg](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/42848/1169) explained what happened.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The fact that `\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry}` "fixes" this problem is a clear symptom of the "fragile command in a moving argument" disease.

You probably have a fragile command in a section title and are using a document class with headers; thus, depending on the pagination, the offending title may or not be used for the header. If it is, the error shows up.

The most probable cause of this is a math formula in a section title

```
\section{A title with a formula \(a+b\)}
```

Fix: say

```
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
```

in the preamble or use `$` to delimit math in section titles

```
\section{A title with a formula $a+b$}
```

There's another problem with math in section titles used for headers: also the letters in the formula will be uppercased. The fix I suggest is to use `fancyhdr` or `titleps` and their method for not uppercasing text in headers or say

```
\usepackage[overload]{textcase}
```

that invokes David Carlisle's `textcase` package in such a way that `\MakeUppercase` is changed into a math-savvy command.

Comment: Yup—the title was `\(u\)-substitutions`.  My next problem was to avoid having the header written as 'U-SUBSTITUTIONS'; I finally settled on `\def\u{\(u\)}\title{\protect\u-substitutions}`.

Comment: @LSpice There's a simpler fix, see edit

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work for me.  (To be specific, I tried `textcase`, but not `fancyhdr` or `titleps`.)

Comment: Wow,  I'd forgotten about that package:-)

Comment: @LSpice Yes, you're right: `textcase` doesn't work with `\(...\)` and `fixltx2e`. :(